# Overload or Optional Parameters

Tags: method-overloading

When I have a function that might, or might not receive a certain parameter, is it better to overload the function, or to add optional args?

If each one has it's ups and downs - when would I use each?

Comment: From the optimization perspective having optional parameters is a better option.

Comment: Related: [Are optional parameters helpful or a hindrance to application maintenance?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/22559/are-optional-parameters-helpful-or-a-hindrance-to-application-maintenance) and [When is method overloading appropriate?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/135313/when-is-method-overloading-appropriate)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the language supports them properly (e.g. type-safety, if applicable), I would prefer optional arguments for the following reasons:

- They convey your intent better so noone suspects that your function overload will do something different (which it probably shouldn't anyway).
- Less code to maintain, even if the function overload only delegates to the more comprehensive one. If you want to rename the function later, you have at least 3 places to do it (two definitions + one call).
- The compiler (if any) might generate smaller binaries.
- Optional arguments scale better, at least in some languages. What if you want to have 3 optional arguments with the ability to mix and match? For full flexibility, you'd need 6 overloads to do that.
- If it's an object method, multiple overloads will greatly hinder the implementation of overrides in subclasses.

Comment: Wouldn't you need 8? Three optional arguments `a`, `b` and `c` has these possibilities: nothing, a, b, c, ab, ac, bc, abc. It's `2^n` for different types, not `n!`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a constructor kind of situation: I often choose a fluent builder pattern to prevent situations with many options.

Eg.`Ordering.natural().onResultOf(function).reverse().compound(Ordering.natural().onResultOf(function2))` is an example of calling a fluent builder interface implemented in Guava.

Of course you now need a separate object to hold the state of your builder, but you reduce overall complexity by separating behavior of constructing from behavior of the constructed.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.